Local Wordpress from Live shows blank page for posts and theme customizer
I downloaded my LIVE Wordpress website files and its database and set it up locally. I imported the database then changed in wp_options the value of home and siteurl to point to my local setup. I also commented the siteground redirect in .htaccess. So now, I can log in to the admin of my local Wordpress but when I want to post something or I want to customize the theme, it only shows me a blank page. How do I make the local version of my live website function correctly?
I tried chaning themes.
I also tried reinstalling xampp then reinstalling the files.
I also changed define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ); to true;

I have already found the culprit! I deactivated all of my plugins and checked if I can post and customize any theme and it worked. So, one of my plugins is actually causing the trouble.
